# Codeigniter 4 assets PATH configuration for Modules

Tags: codeigniter, path, codeigniter-4

I m creating different directories for Role-based access in Codeigniter 4. I have created the Modules directory inside app/ i.e (app/modules/admin). I have assets for the admin. I want to load it in the header file of view. I have tried it with the base_url().'/app/modules/admin/assets/filename.xyz' but load the complete file in the link but doesn't show me the assets. How can, I load these assets in the same directory.  Please see the below code

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo(base_url().'/app/modules/super/assets/'); ?>plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">`

Comment: All the assets should be in public folder, CI4 puts restrictions on any other folders hence you should place static assets in public/modules/super/* and etc.  Than you can refer to the same using base_url().'/modules/super/xyz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All public files including assets should be placed inside your public folder and not your app folder. Your app folder shouldn't be visible to the public.

With this in mind what I would do would be create a simular structure in your public folder.

```
public/modules/admin/css
public/modules/admin/js
public/modules/admin/img
```

Then if you have an asset called styles that would be in:

```
public/modules/admin/css/styles.css
```

This asset should be called using the base_url function from the uri helper.

```
<link src="<?php echo base_url('modules/admin/css/styles.css'); ?>">
```